# how to convert array of string to array of number

Tags: javascript, arrays, string, sum, numbers

I have an array in javascript

```
["666", "321", "333"]
```

i want to convert it to

```
[666, 321, 333]
```

to get the sum of that array values

Please help.

Comment: `const newArr = arr.map(Number)`;

Comment: Have you attempted to solve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use [`Array#reduce`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce) and sum the value which is converted to number by an [unary plus `+`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Arithmetic_Operators#Unary_plus).

```js
var array = ["666", "321", "333"],
    sum = array.reduce((s, v) => s + +v, 0);
    
console.log(sum);
```

Answer (score 8):

Simply use

```
let arr2 = arr1.map(Number);
```

Answer (score 1):

**Convert to Number**

```
["666", "321", "333"].map( s => +s )
```

**Sum of values**

```
["666", "321", "333"].reduce( ( a, c ) => a+(+c), 0 )
```

Answer (score -1):

You can simply try like this.

```
var arr=["666", "321", "333"];
var result=arr.map(Number);
result[3] // 71
typeof(result[3]) // "number"
```

you  will get array values.

Comment: `result[3] == undefined` arrays start at 0.